# Meaning of となら and とやら in these sentences

Tags: meaning

I've encountered those two words in a manga I'm currently reading. Here are the sentences :

> きさま**となら**まちがいなく勝てるぞ。

I don't know if となら is a specific particle or if it is と+なら(ば) (and in that case is と related to まちがう　or 勝てる?)

> てめえの罠にまんまとかかってやる。完全体**とやら**になるがいい。

I suspect とやら is related to the やら particle and has a meaning close to など... but I have seen somewhere that it is equivalent to one of the uses of the quotation marks in english. Like : You pissed on the rug again! - No I didn't my love, it was the dog! - Right, "the dog"...

Comment: Does と+なら(ば) make sense in context - as in "If I were to go up against you I would most definitely win"?

Comment: @lc: Yup it does but I always thought you could say に勝てる but not と勝てる with that sense (the speaker and hearer are opponents, they don't fight together a third opponent).

Comment: Suggestion: となら seems similar to ときたら；やら might be か and can be combined with particles eg どこへやら行ってしまった and is here とか. If I have understood the sentence as given then the sentence ending might benefit from a 「、」ー＞「〜なるが、いい 」?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### となら

> きさまとならまちがいなく勝てるぞ。

In simple terms, this is と ("with") + なら ("if").  Basically,

> **If** it's **with** you, then there's no doubt I'm gonna win.

### とやら

> てめえの罠にまんまとかかってやる。完全体とやらになるがいい。

This one I was less familiar with.  From the [Daijirin entry for やら](http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%82%84%E3%82%89):

> **やら**
>
> 〔「にやあらむ」の転である「やらん」から。中世後期以降の語〕
> 一 （ 副助 ）
> 体言および体言に準ずる語，一部の副詞，助詞などに付く。
> ...
> ②
> 〔「とやら」の形で〕 はっきり言わずに，ぼかして言うときに用いる。 「山田と－いう人」 「どこと－抜けている人」

"Used to make something vaguer, without stating something definitively."

So in your sample sentence,

> I'm'a let myself get caught in your trap.  Go ahead and become "complete" **or whatever you call it**.

Comment: "I'm'a catch you in your own trap. It'd be great if I got your whole body or something." is not the best translation. I suggest "I'll jump right into your trap. Go ahead and become "complete" or whatever you call it." Given that this is from a manga, I assume the addressee undergoes some kind of transformation which turns them into a 完全体.