# Meaning of まんまと in this sentence

Tags: meaning

Here is the sentence :

> てめえの罠にまんまとかかってやる。

Does まんまと means that the speaker fell into the trap easily or voluntarily? Or is the idea that he is willing to fall into the trap only contained in てやる?

Thanks for your time.

EDIT : The speaker says that after being convinced by the hearer (which he just beat) to let him evolve in order to make the fight interesting. Taking the risk of becoming weaker than his opponent in the process.

Comment: Assuming that is what happend (we only have this sentence and your other question to go on but it fits) まんまと seems to add irony to the speaker's statement.

Comment: yeah your right, I'm gonna edit the question to add something about the  context.

Comment: @Tim: You're probably right given the context, but how does it add irony from its meaning of "artfully, successfully, nicely"?

Comment: I think you need to imagine the statement (1) with and w/o the adverb and (2) how the speaker would have said it: eg "I let you catch me" vs "I let you catch me easily", "I neatly (conveniently?) let you catch me". This is of course subjective, まんまと is typically used with 罠にかかる, but without the adverb there is less scope for irony in how it is said - it becomes very factual.

Comment: @Tim: So the idea is that it didn't take a lot of effort (=it was easy) to catch the speaker because he kindly let it happen, thx. By the way, your responses would fit better in an answer don't you think?

Comment: Thanks. I've put everything into an answer. Let's see if they bring out any new insights.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A native reader may have more definitive understanding but my suggestion is to imagine

(1) the statement with and w/o the adverb and

(2) how the speaker would have said it and what words he might have emphasised: eg "I let you catch me" vs "I let you catch me *easily*", or perhaps "I neatly (conveniently?) let you catch me".

I think まんまと can be used with 罠にかかる by itself so it adds to the irony of the speaker's statement, reminding us how we was in control all along. Without the adverb it becomes very factual, with the adverb we get a better insight into the speaker's intention, and given the situation, he is likely to use one to express his feeling.

---

Just for reference I also looked at the following sample sentences from the "プログレッシブ英和・和英辞典 to confirm my understanding of まんまと

> まんまとだまされた｜
>   I was neatly taken in.
>
> そうまんまとは逃がさないぞ｜
>   I won't let you get away so easily.
>
> 彼はそうやって猿をまんまとおびき寄せた｜
>   In that way he succeeded in enticing the monkey to approach.

Comment: まんまと is a word that we use more for the rhythm (and imagery) that it gives than for the meaning.  It almost has an onomatopoeic quality to it.

Answer (score 0):

まんまと derives from うまうまと, with this reduplicated うま the same as the stem of adjective うまい "tasty; skillful".  See [the Daijirin entry here](http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%BE%E3%82%93%E3%81%BE%E3%81%A8) for more.

Analyzing your sample sentence (with [assistance from dainichi](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/16023/meaning-of-%E3%81%A8%E3%81%AA%E3%82%89-and-%E3%81%A8%E3%82%84%E3%82%89-in-these-sentences/16027#16027)), we get:

> てめえの罠にまんまとかかってやる。
>   -> ((てめえの)罠)に **まんまと** かかって やる。
>   -> ((your) trap) in **skillfully** get-caught give-you[impolite]

The まんまと here implies (to me, at least) that the speaker maintains control of the situation even as they say they will get caught in the listener's trap.  The やる also implies that the speaker, in getting caught, will be doing the listener a favor somehow.  These two together might be rendered in English as follows:

> I'm'a **let myself** get caught in your trap.

Comment: Then, from your litteral translation, it seems that what's skillful/successful is how the speaker maintain control of the situation. Are you sure that what's skillful/successful isn't how the trap has been set? Judging from the position of まんまと in the sentence.

Comment: まんまと is an adverb, and in this context, it is modifying かかってやる.  So the speaker is literally saying something like "[I'll] skillfully get caught for you."  Getting caught skillfully doesn't really make sense in the greater picture until you consider that the skill in getting caught probably relates to some bigger plan that the speaker is hinting at.